# Cloudinary is working just fine from the rails console, but not from the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, storage, cloudinary

I'm building a blog using ruby on rails.

Now I want to implement Cloudinary to handle de images from my development environment.

**I had checked on the Active Storage configuration and also cloudinary, but I'm not able to find the error.
**
I can successfully upload pictures from rails console (rails c), but when I attempt to upload it from the form and click on *create article*, it displays the following error message:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDSaj.png)

> **Missing configuration for the cloudinary Active Storage service. Configurations available for the test and local services.**

```
#line 15

14  def create
15    @article = Article.new(article_params)
16    if @article.save
17      redirect_to @article
18    else
```

Can someone give me a hand to find out where is the error and how to fix it?
**The project code is available here:
https://github.com/ThePalmeraTech/la-central**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload the picture to Cloudinary now

controller code:

```
 def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if params[:article][:photo].present?
      uploaded_image = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:article][:photo])
    end

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You [don't have cloudinary set](https://github.com/ThePalmeraTech/la-central/blob/master/config/environments/development.rb#L37) as your active storage service, and [you don't have cloudinary storage service configured](https://github.com/ThePalmeraTech/la-central/blob/master/config/storage.yml)

Assuming you're using [the cloudinary gem](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem), scroll down to the Active Storage Integration section and step through the setup docs.

Comment: Yes I do have both configured and set. I got to upload the pictures to cloudinary from the form now, the problem is that it is not being displayed in the views. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Those are links to your own project showing that you don't have those set.

Comment: Aww, I see what you mean now.

Well, the current version is in the "cloudinary-cdn" branch, where I do have those configuration done. In the case of storage.yml file, I'm providing my keys in ".env" and avoiding to get that published on github.

Thank you Smathy!